# Contact us form in ASP.NET MVC using Umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco, umbraco7

I am new to Umbraco and ASP.NET MVC and I am working on a contact us form in Umbraco 7.

I created the controller and and the view but i am getting the error

> Could not find a Surface controller route in the RouteTable for controller name ContactUsSurfaceController

My model:

```
public class ContactUs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string Company { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string Email { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string Tel { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string Intrested { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

My controller

```
public class ContactUsSurfaceController : SurfaceController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contact(ContactUs model)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendFormat("<p>name: {0}</p>", model.Name);
            sb.AppendFormat("<p>name: {0}</p>", model.Company);
            sb.AppendFormat("<p>name: {0}</p>", model.Email);
            sb.AppendFormat("<p>name: {0}</p>", model.Tel);
            sb.AppendFormat("<p>name: {0}</p>", model.Intrested);
            sb.AppendFormat("<p>name: {0}</p>", model.Message);
            umbraco.library.SendMail("test@test.com", "test@test.com", "Contact Us", sb.ToString(), true);
            return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
           }
        return JavaScript("alert('error')");
       }
    }
}
```

My view for this model:

```
    @model Umbraco.AddingValues.Web.Model.ContactUs
    @using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm("Contact", "ContactUsSurfaceController", null, new { @class = "contact-form" }))
    { 
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div>

    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)

    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Email)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Email)

    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Tel)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Tel)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Tel)

    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Intrested)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Intrested)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Intrested)

    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Message)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Message)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Message)

   </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn-accept" />
  }
```

and I call this in another view like this

```
    @Html.Action("~/Views/Partials/ContactForm.cshtml")
```

Please help me to resolve the error I get

> Could not find a Surface controller route in the RouteTable for controller name ContactUsSurfaceController

Comment: there is a problem with routes plz post routeconfig file here.

Comment: Hi dear, I do not find any App-Start folder in it.

Comment: there must be a way of control routing in umbraco then post that thing over here because the problen u r facing is due to routing problem...

Comment: Not familiar with umbraco, but should the second parameter in `@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm("Contact", "ContactUsSurfaceController", null..` be `"ContactUs"` or "`ContactUsSurface"`?

Comment: Agree with Stephen, convention dictates action: "ContactUs"  and controller: "ContactUsSurface"

Comment: yes u right it work :)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 @using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm("Contact", "ContactUsSurfaceController", null, new { @class = "contact-form" }))
```

To:

```
@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<ContactUsSurfaceController>("Contact"))
```